# Why can't I pass these parameters to my command?

Tags: bash

```
B=master U='my.email@email.com' curl -u "${U}" "https://bitbucket.org/myteam/pod-dev/raw/${B}/install.bash"
```

I get asked:

```
Enter host password for user '':
```

See, the "U" is missing.

And also curl is performed:

```
GET /myteam/pod-dev/raw//install.bash HTTP/1.1
```

Also here, the B is missing (branch)

```
macOS Sierra 10.12.2

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 4):

Variables assignments like you are using them are part of the command. In your case the shell will try to expand `"${A}"`, `"${B}"` before they have been actually set - *during* parsing the command.

You can separate the variable assignments and the actual command by `;`:

```
B=master; U='my.email@email.com'; curl -u "${U}" "https://bitbucket.org/myteam/pod-dev/raw/${B}/install.bash"
```

That way they are 3 separate commands.

Comment: Thank you! It just seemed to wierd (when you're use to `X=Y ./this_script.sh`), but totally sensible now that u say it.

Answer (score 2):

bash will try to expand the variables first, but you haven't set them at this point. See for example:

```
$ x=foo echo "$x"
>

$ x=foo; echo "$x"
> foo
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this instead of your command:

```
export B=master; export U='my.email@email.com' ; curl -u "$U" "https://bitbucket.org/myteam/pod-dev/raw/$B/install.bash"
```

Comment: I dont want to export